# Jquery two elements, toggles on focus/click ... works but lags

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, jquery-events

This works as I want it to http://jsfiddle.net/nosfan1019/gvQYh/  but there is a noticeable delay if the focus/click changes to a sibling element.  Any ideas?

Comment: When I tried your demo the "lag" I was seeing was entirely due to how long I held the mouse button down because your focusout handler is triggered by the mouse _down_ event but your focus/click handler on the parent div seems to get triggered only on mouse _up_.

Comment: I didn't notice that.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Should give me a better starting point.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (`<input>, <select>, etc.`) and links (`<a href>`).

```
$('#ooo').bind('focus click', function () {
    $('#kkk').text('hello');
});

$('#ooo').blur( function () { // you can use `blur` handler
    $('#kkk').empty();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gvQYh/1/

Comment: Well the idea is that if the user's focus is anywhere in the parent div #ppp, the "hello" text will appear ... I.e. not just when the input has the focus.

Comment: The real estate is going to be much smaller with several rows of similar functionality.  It would be jumping around too much if I did that.  I guess the lags something I'll have to live with?

Comment: @RyanGrush: Could you update your fiddle with a bit more html to better reflect your real situation with several rows? I have a couple of ideas that might help but I want to see your real html to be sure I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

After a little wrangling I have a solution :)

```
$('#ooo').focus(function () {
    $('#kkk').text('hello');
    visible = true;
});


$('* :not(#ooo)').focus( function() {
    if (visible) {
       $('#kkk').empty();
       visible = false;
    }
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nosfan1019/3nK84/